# Maximum Value of Monolayer Capacity

Tags: physical-chemistry, absorption

What is the possible maximum value of the monolayer capacity? Is it possible for the monolayer capacity to exceed more than $(100)\frac{mol}{g}$ or even $(1000)\frac{mol}{g}$? Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.